# Highest reaching sounding rocket

Tags: sounding-rocket

What is the highest reaching sounding rocket?

Black Brant XII can reack 1,500 km, is there any other sounding rocket that can reach even higher?

Comment: Perhaps you could reword your question to be "_has_ reached even higher". There's plenty of rockets that could probably escape Earth entirely even with the gravity losses associated with burning straight up...

Comment: True but OTOH its not sure how high BB12 actually reached, comparing to how high it can reach. Its interesting to know though both things: if any rocket is more powerful and if any rocket actually reached higher than BB12

Comment: Just to clarify what I'm getting at, current Voyager 2 holds the "altitude" record... so Titan IV?

Comment: But Titan IV is not a sounding rocket. And the launch was not suborbital. I dont get your point

Comment: This is why I pointed out you might not want to discuss hypothetical. Fly a Titan IV straight up on some suborbital trajectory and it's a sounding rocket...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed in the most recent [NASA sounding rocket annual report](https://sites.wff.nasa.gov/code810/files/Annual%20Report%202019_web.pdf) that the Oriole IV has slightly better performance than the Black Brant XII. However, based on [astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/o/orioleiv.html) I don't think any mission has actually reached 1500 km.

[image: sounding rocket vehicle performance]

Comment: Meanwhile I found this - China reported the launch of a suborbital high altitude sounding rocket [more properly, a vertical probe] on May 13 to an altitude of more than (but of order?) 10000 km, and possibly of order 30,000 km - WOW - https://www.globalsecurity.org/space/world/china/kunpeng-7.htm